# Remove null values from displaying in ArcView 10 labels

Tags: vbscript, arcgis

I am trying to create a three tierd label in which the third row is a year.  However some of the data does not have a year.  I would like these labels to show as only two tiers i.e. a blank.  At the moment ArcView 10 is automatically inserting a 0 in all these labels.  Below is my attempt to sort this but it is not working.  Bear in mind I am not used to working in vbScript so please respond using very simple words!

```
Function FindLabel ( [SubCmpt], [Species], [P Year] )
  FindLabel = Function FindLabel ( [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species] & vbCrLf & [P Year] )
  if ( [P Year] = '0') then
   FindLabel = [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species]
  else
FindLable = [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species] &vbCrLf & [P Year] 
End Function
```

Thank you in advance for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with ArcGIS, but I'd expect `Null` (a particular value indicating invalid data) and `'0'` (the string "0") to be different values. VBScript provides a special function (`IsNull()`) to test for `Null` values, so try `IsNull([P Year])` instead of `[P Year] = '0'`.

You'll probably get better answers on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure what the first line of your function is supposed to do:

```
FindLabel = Function FindLabel ( [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species] & vbCrLf & [P Year] )
```

You don't need it.

Second, you need to spell "FindLabel" the same way every time.

Third, use IsNull to detect null (as @Ansgar said).

Fourth, in VBA, you need to end your If-Else statement with `End If`.

In summary, try this:

```
Function FindLabel ( [SubCmpt], [Species], [P Year] )
  If IsNull([P Year]) Then
    FindLabel = [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species]
  Else
    FindLabel = [SubCmpt] & vbCrLf & [Species] & vbCrLf & [P Year] 
  End If
End Function
```